# How to save downloaded files in the cache folder of the app's memory?

Tags: java, android, rest, android-asynctask, android-download-manager

I'm aware similar questions have been asked before but there really isn't a working solution. I am downloading multiple PDF files through the DownloadManager and I want to save these files into the cache folder of the app's memory but couldn't find any way of doing that.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myList.add("https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/Actionscript%20-%20Flash%20-%20Flex%20-%20Air/Flash%20Development%20for%20Android%20Cookbook%20-%20Labrecque%20-%20Packt%20%282011%29/Flash%20Development%20for%20Android%20Cookbook%20-%20Labrecque%20-%20Packt%20%282011%29.pdf");
        myList.add("http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD143X/dkand11/Group1Mads/andreas.ulvesand.daniel.eriksson.report.pdf");
        myList.add("http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/allalaadimised/reading/Android-Programming-Cookbook.pdf");
        myList.add("https://x.coe.phuket.psu.ac.th/warodom/242-320/ebook/9781785883262-ANDROID_PROGRAMMING_FOR_BEGINNERS.pdf");
        myList.add("https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~bam/uicourse/830spring09/BFeiginMobileApplicationDevelopment.pdf");
        myList.add("https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-1_0-CC.pdf");

        btn = findViewById(R.id.download_btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse(myList.get(i));
                    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
                    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                    Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files)

> **Internal storage**:
>   It's always available. Files saved here are accessible by only your
>   app. When the user uninstalls your app, the system removes all your
>   app's files from internal storage.

Android built-in download manager can't access your app internal storage, so you can only save your files into an external storage directory just by calling `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` or `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir`.

But if you want to save them in your internal storage, just register a receive and then copy files from the external to internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the local destination for the downloaded file using.

```
request.setDestinationUri(Uri uri)
```

you need to use `context.getCacheDir()` to get cache directory and save your file to cache.

Finally, in your paths xml add below code to allow provider to get uri.

```
<cache-path name="cache_files" path="."  />
```

Comment: Where do you use `context.getCacheDir();`?

Comment: And also.  Where do I find paths.xml?

Comment: Any update on this please? How can the app's internal storage or cache be chosen in download manager request?